# How to add view of second component to current page from angular2

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-template

In basic, I have one component with integer data in list and second component with action (like +1 operation) I want to open app`('/')`, click by one of integer and redirect to other page`(/int/13)`. On this page i want to see old list of integers data and my `number + 1` (14).

My routes is this

```
  {path: '', component: IntegerComponent,
  {path: 'int/:id', component: ActionComponent}
```

After open (/) i see integer data from IntegerComponent

```
<li *ngFor="let int of ints [routerLink]="['/int', int]">
  <p>{{int | json}}</p>
</li>
```

And after click i really see `int number + 1`, but i need to see this with integer data together, on one page. Without reloading data from server. Only adding new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find answer by myself!! Need to use `children` for routing and in int template add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. Then, if user is clicked by int - result of action will show in this outlet, and main outlet will keep